# Parse numbers at positions in a given string

Tags: c++, pointers

I have `std::string` with value `1T23`:

How can I get `x = 1, y = 2, z = 3`;

I tried:

```cpp
int x = std::atoi(&myString.at(0));
int y = std::atoi(&myString.at(2));
int z = std::atoi(&myString.at(3));
```

but it returned: `x = 0, y = 23, z = 3`?

Comment: Will the numbers always be one-digit? Will the string always have 4 characters? Will te separator always be `'T'`?

Comment: Just subtract `’0’` from the character at requested position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int x = std::stoi(myString.substr(0, 1));
int y = std::stoi(myString.substr(2, 1));
int z = std::stoi(myString.substr(3, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's all sigle digits, it could be simple:

```
int x = myString.at(0) - '0';
int y = myString.at(2) - '0';
int z = myString.at(3) - '0';
```

Of course, you need to handle potential exceptions (e.g. `myString` has less than 4 characters). `at` operator can throw [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

Also consider what if the interested chars are not digits in `myString`.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) will treat the input as a `char const *`, and try to convert from that position to the null-terminator.

In this case

```
int x = std::atoi(&myString.at(0));
```

the string `1T23` is converted to an `int`. Since this conversion is not possible, you get the result of `0`.

For the other cases:

```
int y = std::atoi(&myString.at(2));  // converts "23" to 23
int z = std::atoi(&myString.at(3));  // converts "3" to 3
```

You can get the actual numbers by using [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and using the appropriate substrings. Alternatively, since you only want single digits, you could index into the string, and subtract `'0'`. The other answers show how to do this exactly.